# why ethereum wallet keeps on "Downloading new node" and doesn't move to sync or anywhere else?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, nodes

I 've just installed the wallet from github it all went good but now I m stuck with that downloading new nodes stuff and it doesn't seem to go further to sync or anywhere else. Mac OS X 10.9.5 Mac Pro mid 2012.